# Describing a Markov Process in terms of its waiting times

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, exponential-distribution

I have a Markov process $Q_t$ with a certain jump rate $\sigma$. In this certain Markov process we can only jump to the neighbouring right state and the jumping distance is $\varepsilon>0$. At $Q_0$ the process needs a random amount of time $T_1$ before jumps to the new state. Until it jumps to the next state, it needs another random amount of time, $T_2$, and so on. All those waiting times $T_1, T_2, T_3,\dots$ are exponentially distributed continuous random variables, i.e. $T_i\sim \text{exp}(\sigma)$, which are independent.
Then with
\begin{align}
  \widetilde{T_k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}T_i
 \end{align}
one can define the time of the $k$-th jump or in other words the waiting time till the $k$-th jump.

Now my question would be the following: Is there a way of expressing the whole Markov process in terms of the $\widetilde{T_k}$?

Comment: What you described is a Poisson process $N_t$ in disguise, except that the states are not the natural numbers but some other discrete states. Clearly the states of $Q_t$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the states of $N_t$ and we know that $N_t=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1_{\{\tau_k\le t\}}$ where $\tau_k$ is the standard notation for the jump time $\widetilde{T}_k$.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks, I didn't notice that! So then a homogeneous Poisson process is a special Markov process with continuous time and discrete state space?

Comment: Yes . The homogeneous Poisson process is the second most important process to know about as much as one can. Unfortunately only few books go into a lot of details - unlike for the more ubiquitous Brownian motion. A noticeable exception when I studied was the book *Introduction to Stochastic Processes applied to Finance* by D. Lamberton and B. Lapeyre .

Comment: I'll definitely look into that one! Thanks a lot!